# required_if works incorrect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use the following validation rule:

```
 'email' => 'required_if:phone-register,false|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

And my incoming data are:

```
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "xPGUfppYirlLmSezTQduKZV4NXUAqf3I5DhrSJTZ"
  "email" => null
  "phone" => "514033390"
  "phone-register" => "true"
  "password" => "1234567"
  "password_confirmation" => "1234567"
]
```

Despite on I have incoming `email` as null, the validation for `email` still works. Why, if I set `required_if:phone-register,false`

Full code of validation:

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required_if:phone-register,"false"|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'phone-register' => 'required|boolean',
            'phone' => 'required_if:phone-register,"true"|numeric|min:6|max:15'
        ]);
```

Now I have:

```
 protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        $v =  Validator::make($data, [
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'phone-register' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required_unless:phone-register,true|numeric|min:6'
        ]);

        $v->sometimes('email', 'required|email|max:255|unique:users', function ($input) {
            return $input->phone-register === "false";
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're wrapping `true` and `false` in quotes within the validation rules? Try removing the quotes. And if that still doesn't work, try using `1` and `0` for `true` and `false` everywhere instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add rules conditionally](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules):

```
$v = Validator::(....);

$v->sometimes('email', 'required|email|max:255|unique:users', function ($input) {
    return $input->phone-register === "false";
});
```

Comment: It does not work. I updated my question with full list of validation

Comment: Yes, I am sure, it is always true of false

Comment: @Darama I've updated my answer. Also, make sure `false` is a string in the array.

Comment: So, afetr I need to return $v?

Comment: @Darama yes, just `return $v;`

Comment: Fro where to get `$input?` I posted this in questin

Comment: I get an error: `Use of undefined constant register - assumed 'register'`

Comment: After also one error: `FatalThrowableError in RegistersUsers.php line 31:
Call to a member function validate() on null`